# Disable swipe back gesture in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Been looking around on here for a while but can't seem to find a working solution.

I'm trying to disable the swipe to go back to previous view gesture, in Swift.

I've tried a variety of solutions including:

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = false
```

and

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self

func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer!) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Is there a new method of doing this or some other method that works?

Comment: It's causing an issue when a user doesn't fully swipe, and interferes with the nature of the UI we are using (seeking time in an audio track)

Comment: Well, I don't want to derail your question, but I suggest you (1) resolve the doesn't-fully-swipe issue and (2) indent your audio track seeking UI so it's not so close to the edge. This is expected UX, and is especially important for iPhone 6 Plus and iPad users where it's kind of a hassle to get to the navigation bar.

Comment: Anyway, your code should disable the gesture recognizer. Does it work on older versions of iOS?

Comment: Ah good point about iPhone 6 - maybe I'll look at modifying the dealloc method - but I'll still leave the question open as I'm interested nonetheless

Comment: I'm testing on iOS 8 as the minimum

Comment: I was able to do it with returning false in gestureRecognizerShouldBegin. Are you getting callback at gestureRecognizerShouldBegin ? Maybe you put this code in wrong view controller...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could disable it but that would not be to recommended as most iOS users go back by swiping and less by pressing the back button. 
If you want to disable it it would be more reasonable to use a `modal segue` instead of a push segue which is not that big of a transfer. 
If you really want to get rid of the swipe to go back function I would just disable the back button and have a done button on the top right of the screen.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 185):

The following is an easy approach to disabling & re-enabling the swipe back.

**Swift 3.x & up**

In a viewDidLoad/willAppear/didAppear method add:

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

Just keep in mind that if you do it with `viewDidLoad`, then the next time you open the view, it may not be set depending upon whether or not it remains in your stack.

Unless you want it to remain off, you will need to turn it back on when the view is closed via either `willMove(toParentViewController:)` or `willDisappear`. Your `navigationController` will be nil at `viewDidDisappear`, so that is too late.

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
```

A special note on **SplitViewControllers**:

As pointed out by CompC in the comments, you will need to call the second navigation controller to apply it to a detail view as such:

```
navigationController?.navigationController?.interactivePopGe‌​stureRecognizer?.isE‌​nabled = false
```

**Swift 2.2 & Objective-C**

Swift versions 2.x & below:

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.enabled
```

Objective-C:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled
```

Comment: I was having a bit of trouble getting this to work, until I realized that since the view controller I was trying to disable this for was on the detail side of the Split View Controller, it's technically in a separate navigation controller (even though, when collapsed, it looks like it's in the same controller). 

To get around this I had to do:

    `navigationController?.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false`

Comment: @CompC Thanks for the update, never had that scenario, so good to know.

Comment: it is sufficient to disable it in didAppear, and re-enable it on willDisappear. Especially re-enable it on didDisappear is useless, because navigationController property is nil already.

Comment: Is it possible to disable this on through out app? like code in AppDelegate etc.?

Comment: @iajmeri43 Yes, create a subclass of UINavigationController, and then set the property in its viewDidLoad. As long as the nav controller is utilized by all the views you want within the app, it will work.

Comment: Thought I'd point out that interactivePopGestureRecorgizer may not be initialized depending on when/where you try to set navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false. I'm using coordinators and this was nil after I initialized the NavController and before I pushed the first ViewController.

Comment: Thanks @TMin, I've used this when initializing navigation controllers without incident, but it is useful to see spots where it slips through.

Answer (score 23):

I was able to do this by returning false in gestureRecognizerShouldBegin

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
}

func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: Note `UIGestureRecognizer!` in the OP's code vs. `UIGestureRecognizer` here.

Answer (score 19):

Add this line before pushing view controller to navigation controller

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 7):

Nothing wrong with either answer from Hari or Stefan but this is more succinct. Just put it in viewDidLoad and you're done.

```
if navigationController!.respondsToSelector(Selector("interactivePopGestureRecognizer")) {
    navigationController!.view.removeGestureRecognizer(navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer)
}
```

**EDIT:**

One small caveat is that if the Navigation Controller was opened by another view and the Navigation Controller is closed then you'll get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. To fix it you have to save the original UIGestureRecognizer and put it back when you exit the view.

Declare:

```
private var popGesture: UIGestureRecognizer?
```

Immediately before removing the gesture:

```
popGesture = navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer
```

Then when closing the view:

```
If popGesture != nil {
    navigationController!.view.addGestureRecognizer(popGesture!)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

`self.navigationController.pushViewController(VC, animated: Bool)`

call

`self.navigationController.setViewContollers([VC], animated: Bool)`

`setViewControllers` *replaces* the all the VCs on the stack, instead of *adding* a new controller on top. This means that the new set VC is the root VC, and the user cannot go back.

This is most effective when you only want to disable the swipe on a single VC, and keep the swipe-to-back for the other VC.

If you want users to be able to go back, just not through swiping, do not use this method as it will disable all backs (as there is no VC to go back to).

Answer (score 4):

RowanPD's logic for **Swift 4**

```
private var popGesture: UIGestureRecognizer?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if navigationController!.responds(to: #selector(getter: UINavigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer)) {
        self.popGesture = navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer
        self.navigationController!.view.removeGestureRecognizer(navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!)
    }

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if let gesture = self.popGesture {
        self.navigationController!.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

for objective -c

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillAppear:true];

  self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is something you missed if it doesn't work after you tried all.

1. Add `navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false`
    to your viewWillAppear(animated:) method.
2. if it doesn't work, remove navigation delegate from the view controller. Check again if your view controller is confirming `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocols. if so, just remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I generally make sure that swipe back is enabled in as many places as possible, even adding a custom gesture recognizer to add it to modal screens. However for an authentication and download process in my app I start the process with a modal navigation controller and then push the view for each next step. However, once it's completed I want to prevent them from backing up into the authentication screens.

For this scenario I've been using:

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

in `viewWillAppear()` on the final screen. You can undo these in `viewWillDisappear()` if you're pushing another view and need them there.

Answer (score 1):

Come here a little bit late. In my case `self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false;` not working. So I do this: you can present view controller instead of push view controller. This way the swipe back gesture will not apply to the view controller.

```
navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true)
```

You could use dismiss for your custom back button

```
self.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Note: You could set VC modal presentation style before present it to make sure it's full screen.

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If requirement is to show side  menu on some of the screens then add AddScreenEdgePanGesture on this specific view instead of navigationController view

replace it

```
SideMenuManager.default.menuAddScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresent(toView: self.navigationController?.view)
```

with this

```
SideMenuManager.default.menuAddScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresent(toView: self.view)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only **complete removal of the gesture recognizer** worked for me (from the presenting view controller).

```
if let navigationController = parent.navigationController,
   let interactivePopGestureRecognizer = navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer {
    navigationController.view.removeGestureRecognizer(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use this if you don't want to come back, or you set the new rootViewController.

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(VC, animated: Bool)
```

Use this

```
self.navigationController.setViewContollers([VC], animated: Bool)
```

setViewControllers Remove all the View Controllers on the stack then the user cannot go back. it will disable all backs

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10, coordinateSpace: .global))
```

so minimum distance is the distance to which drag gesture  start listening, setting to 0 removes any listening, but it will remove all interactions be aware, i have changed 0 to 10 to listen to tap gestures, but in your screen if you have any other interaction it will not work after adding this,

Comment: You should explain how this works.

Answer (score -4):

If you don't care about system back button appearance (for example, if you're using custom back button or navigation bar is hidden at all), it might help you:

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

It hides back button and disables swipe back gesture.