# VoiceOver's two-finger scrub gesture not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I am trying two-finger scrub gesture (draw a Z on the screen using two fingers) on iPhone when voiceOver is ON but it's not working while default back gesture is working without voiceOver.

I have created a custom back button and have also tried the below link to enable it.
Visit [Disable swipe back gesture in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731751/disable-swipe-back-gesture-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the specific issue, you can work around it by implementing [`accessibilityPerformEscape()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1615091-accessibilityperformescape) and popping the top view controller on escape.