# Two Swipe Gesture Recognizer on ViewController, only one works?

Tags: ios, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have two Swipe Gesture Recognizers on my ViewController. One works fine, when I swipe right it goes back to the previous View. However, the recent one I added doesn't work at all. I have set it to go to a different View Controller when I swipe left but, nothing happens. I didn't add any code for the first Swipe Gesture Recognizer so shouldn't this additional one also be able to work without code?

Answer (score 1):

It goes back because the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` handles that, not your swipe recognizer.

You need to do two things:

1. Wire your gesture recognizers to IBAction calls within your view controller so that it can handle them
2. Disable the pop gesture recognizer so that it will not conflict with your desired behavior ([See answer here for how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731751/disable-swipe-back-gesture-in-swift/38793907#38793907))

Comment: Thanks. So in the IBAction I just have a call a performsegue with identifier right? I already have a push segue set up and gave it an identifier but my ViewController file isn't able to recognise the idenfitier?

Comment: @George If the only thing you want is for it to navigate to the previous & next pages, then you can remove your swipe right one and rely on the interactivePopGesture. For the right one, you can call performSegue and provide it with the identifier given to the desired segue. If you want additional functionality though, then you need both recognizers & would need to set up an unwind segue for the return.

Comment: What you said makes no sense, I removed the right swipe gesture and I can no longer swipe back. I start on Screen 1, swipe right and go to Screen 2, I can already swipe right to go back to Screen 1. The problem is I can't swipe left to go to Screen 3.I have a segue set up to go to Screen 3 with an Identifier but its not recognised when I refer to it.