# Overriding back swipe gesture in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How to override gesture to pop to rootViewController, not to previous ViewController?

Comment: I don't think you can modify the default gesture behavior. You'll probably need to disable the default gesture and add your own gesture recognizer and transition behavior.

Comment: @Greg, as i thought, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a combination of the following:

Add a swipe gesture recognizer to your view controller:

[image]

Add the following to your view controller class:

```
import UIKit

class SwipeBackViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
    }

    @IBAction func swipeback(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

- The command in `viewDidLoad` disables the default swipe recogninzer in iOS
- Then, the action associated with the swipe recognizer you added above handles the pop for you

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731751/disable-swipe-back-gesture-in-swift/38793907#38793907) goes into disabling the recognizer in more detail in case you have any questions on that.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can set delegate of this gesture in viewController, in  viewController's viewDidLoad.
It looks like :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }
```

and customize it's methods in view controller. For example:

```
       func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive event: UIEvent) -> Bool {
        print("event \(event.description)")
        return true
   }
```

If you set returning value for false - pop action will not be triggered

For me it worked like :

```
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive event: UIEvent) -> Bool {
        showAlertViewController()
        return false
   }
```

If you need this behaviour only once, you should set delegate back in viewController's deinit method

```
    deinit {
        navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = navigationController
    }
```