# how to delete swipe up to back function

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

when I use segue to go back in some part in my app this unnecessary function appear.
I try to cancel it by write
 `navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false`

but it cancels only the navigation controller auto generated back button but it isn't cancel the auto generated swipe up go back function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731751/disable-swipe-back-gesture-in-swift may be this link can help you

Comment: non of this options help