# Xamarin iOS disable navigation swipe effect

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm new to mobile development and I wanted to ask about a way to switch pages without the navigation swipe effect, just press the button and the required page will appear instead of the old one. I thought about the TabbedPage but it won't work with my UI.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you push the screen, just write to animate argument false

```
await Navigation.PushAsync (newPage, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [interactivePopGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621847-interactivepopgesturerecognizer?language=objc) to disable navigation swipe effect .

Just create a renderer for Page , and do it in `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` method .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Page), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.iOS
{
    class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

            if (NavigationController != null)
            {
                NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to [Disable swipe back gesture in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731751/disable-swipe-back-gesture-in-swift).